# Compact and convex properties of the set $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | 1 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 2 \}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, convex-analysis, compactness

As the title states, I am trying to determine if the given set $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | 1 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 2 \}$ is compact / convex.

---

Progress so far:

Convex property:

This question has been taken from an old exam paper, where I used a double derivative in a previous question to determine the convex property for a $f''(x) \geq 0 \ \ \forall x \in [a,b]$. Can I apply a similar approach here?

Compact property:

For this to be satisfied it needs to be closed and bounded. I understand bounded to mean that the set is finite, and closed to mean that there are clear boundaries of the set. based on this (not particularly mathematical) intuition, I believe the set to be compact.

Comment: I'm afraid "convex" has a different meaning in the exam question than in the graph-of-a-function question, and second derivatives are not the way to go. In fact, it's much easier than that, if you just check out the definition of "convex".

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for nudging me in the right direction. I noticed that the donut shape in this question is even given as an example of a non convex set in the wiki article I read. I still feel like I don't have a firm grasp on the compact property though

Answer (score 0):

It is compact, it is not convex.

Closed and bounded subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ are compact.

The formal definition of compact is that every open cover has a finite subcover.  But that is abstract and can be difficult to work with.

Another property of compact sets is that they contain all of their limit points.  Or, every convergent sequence in the set converges to a point in the set.

A set is convex if every line segment between every two points in the set is in the set.

It is not convex as the line from $(-1,0)$ to $(1,0)$ passes a region not in the set.

Comment: What's an "interval" in ${\bf R}^2$?

Comment: Sorry, subset of Euclidean space.

Comment: @DougM Sorry if this is a daft question, but can i say that the inequality is what allows us to say that the set is bound? The closed part of compactness still isn't intuitive to me. Thanks for the clear explanation of the convex property.

Comment: The $x^2+y^2\le2$ says it's bounded. "Closed" means "contains all its limit points".

Comment: The set is bounded if it is of a finite size.  Yes, the inequalities establish the boundaries.  A set is open means if for every point in the set there is a neighborhood such than every point in the neighborhood is also in the set.  A set is closed, if its complement is open.     The quick and dirty.. closed boundaries are $(\le, \ge)$... open bounds are ($<,>$).

Comment: If you are going to get anywhere in real analysis, you must be ready to always go back to the definitions.

Comment: I am encountering these definitions for the first time. The wiki definition for neighborhoods refers to open sets, and the circular definitions are causing confusion for me.